# Ability to Configure Environment Variables for Unit Tests (Specifically xUnit) in Rider

Tags: .net-core, jetbrains-ide, rider

I have an xUnit project which from the IDE I run using the Unit Tests window or the run configuration `All tests from Solution`.

When configuring the `All tests from Solution` run configuration (or creating a new configuration), the name is the only configurable field and there is no way to specify environment variables. I'm using the [Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) pattern to configure and expose my dependency injected resources. I need multi-environment support either through launchSettings or environment variables to configure the HostingEnvironment so different configurations can be tested, but there doesn't seem to be this capability in Rider. I *think* based on some search results I saw when searching on the problem that Visual Studio provides this capability for running xUnit / Unit Test projects.

This [forum post](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000566430-How-to-set-Environment-to-Test-for-unit-test-runner-) is old but about the same / similar problem and one of the comments links to this [youtrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-4774) which is marked fixed but then neither comments on that issue nor the comments on any of it's related "fixed" issues say how it was fixed or what the acceptable workaround is.

Answer (score 1):

File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Unit Testing | Test Runner

Comment: I'm aware of that setting but it's not an acceptable workaround. In order to toggle between different configurations, you have to go into settings and change all the environment variables you have configured. I'm hoping there's a better option.

Comment: @DeweyVozel Either contact developer in the issue, or submit a new one via Help->Report a Bug or Help->Contact Support in Rider.

Comment: A better solution might be to do what Intellij IDEA does, allow you to create run configurations for running unit tests. In the run configuration, you can set environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

I too have been researching this sort of support in Rider. So far I've found that in

`Tests > Unit Testing Settings... > Test Runner > Test Settings`

You can specify a `.runsettings` file that will allow you to set Environment Variables via configuration for unit tests.

I haven't yet found a way to switch them out easily nor a way to have them auto detected (so you can just commit it to your repository and have it automatically detected for everyone's test runs), but I'll try to remember to come leave an update here when or if I do figure out those details.